# C++ line justification with I/O

Tags: c++, string, io

I am creating a program that justifies a paragraph to ensure that each line has a length of 75 char. I have created functions that will insert spaces and create these desired lengths as needed, but I am having problems reading a text file and trying to break it down line by line. Each line provided is less than the 75 char limit, and my functions do properly work when it is given only a line. But I do not know how to read line by line, manipulate it, and then write to my new .txt file. When I output this to the new text file, I am greeted by a justified line of text, not text that is in a paragraph block!

I have tried to create an if else loop that would only run when the string.length() is less than 75 char, and would create a new line when false, but I do not know how to create this new line in the program

```cpp
string myString;
string line("\n");

while (getline(inFile, myString))
{
    cout << myString << endl;
    puncLoop(myString);
    spaceLoop(myString);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Order to output the file with new line you can use `"\n"`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    //in file object
    std::ifstream inFile("example.txt");

    //out file object
    std::ofstream outFile ("example2.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc );

    //Checking if file exist
    if( inFile && outFile  )
    {
        //temp valarable to store each line
        std::string mystring;
        //Loop through each line
        while (getline(inFile, mystring)) 
        {
            //... Call Your Business Logic functions here, ( make use of pass by refernce or return to get back the string )

            outFile << mystring.c_str() << "\n";
        }

        //closing file after completing
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open File to read or write"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```